# How do I find the max value in a column only if it contains certain texts in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

The data has numbers in text format and texts with numbers.

How do I find the max of the numbers in text format without converting to numbers?
How do I find the max if it contains certain texts (ie, if it contains only `NB`)?

[image]

Comment: As a result, do you expect just the digits value `667` or the whole cell `NB667`? Also. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: As a result, I expect to be the whole cell "NB667".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula

```
=CONCATENATE(SORTN(ArrayFormula(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT($A$2:A,".*NB"), 
                                         REGEXEXTRACT($A$2:A,"NB(.*)")*1})), 
                       1,2,2,0))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)
- [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Answer (score 2):

### Edit.

You can use `Index` & `Match` to get the reference to the max item in the array and return the matching item from C.

I don't like this approach as your declaring an array twice so the computation is more expensive, I would suggest the answer by @marikamitsos

```
=INDEX(C2:C9,MATCH(MAX(
      ARRAYFORMULA(INT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C9,"NB(\d+)"),0)))),
      ARRAYFORMULA(INT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C9,"NB(\d+)"),0))),0))

NB667
```

[image]

Regex Explanation.

### `NB` matches the characters NB literally (case sensitive)

### 1st Capturing Group `(\d+)`

### `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

### `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: is there a way to show the result as "NB667" with the text ?

Comment: @PurplePapaya see edit, please add your expected output to your post next time :)